# Topological "filters" and convolutions, are they related or is it just a coincidence of name choice?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, convolution, signal-processing, filters

Being an engineer, I have sometimes heard of

1. *Topological filters* and in particular *ultrafilters*. They seem to have some meaning regarding partial ordering of sets but be of a more pure math origin than I am used to.
2. Then there is the signal processing meaning of filter - a function which is *applied* when it is *convolved* with a "signal" (another function):

$$(f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\tau)g(\tau-t)dt$$

I suspect these two usages for the word "filter" may be distinctly different with no intuitive connection. But maybe there is some connection that my lack of studies in pure mathematics does not allow me to see?

Comment: Very often completely different things share the same name. ("Distribution" is among the worst offenders). The connection is language, not mathematics.

Comment: @Kusma But distribution theory is not always a "bad coincidence" in this sense because it really connects continuous probability distributions to discrete ones and lets us do probability analysis on combinations of discrete and continuous ones. For example atomic probabilities you can represent with Dirac delta distributions. There, "represent" is another such word isn't it?

Comment: There is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(differential_geometry) ...

Comment: I mean it **could** have been a coincidence we had those courses at same time, but I think they planned it more cleverly than that happening by pure chance. Just as having FFT and Laplace transforms and probability generating moments at same time would be pure chance.

Comment: @Kusma ah ok, yes I should not speak of those ones. But I think there can be some thought behind using same names in many cases.

Comment: My assertion: No, there is no connection between these two uses of the word "filter".